# Performance penalty when using JUnit Category running tests in maven

Tags: java, junit, categories, maven-surefire-plugin, test-suite

I refactored a project from using test suites to using JUnit Category annotations. I noticed a quite remarkable performance penalty when using categories (factor 4 times slower).

Background:

- ~110 test classes, containing ~400 test methods
- old: these 110 test classes were executed through 11 TestSuites (each maven sub-module has one test-suite)
- new: these 110 test classes are now annotated by the Category `FastTest` (at class level)
- 103 of the test methods are additionally annotated by `SmokeTest` (max. 1 test case per test class)
- SmokeTest interface is a derivation of FastTest

Starting the categorized tests: `mvn test -P fast-tests` rsp. `mvn test -P smoke-tests` (see pom.xml below).

Maven-Output

```
                          Old (suites)    New (FastTest)      new (SmokeTest)
Total time:               02:04 min        07:55 min          06:33 min
Time elapsed (summed up)  95.638 s         102.925 s          51.484
```

The run using the categories lasts nearly 4 times longer (while executing the same amounts of tests). Executing the Smoke-Tests (103 Testcases) lasts nearly as long as executing all 400 Testcases.

Oviously is also the big difference from the reported `Total time` to the summed up `Time elapsed`. Latter seems to be only the time measured within the test method, without surfire overhead (starting JVM, etc.).

It seems that the surfire plugin needs quite a lot of time only by introspecting the Category annotations.

Is there a possibility to overcome this performance penalty? Note: Since the productive code under test needs to initialize/finalize a global library (with access to native libraries, which cannot be done in parallel on the same system) I am tight to use succesive execution (no fork, no parallel, etc.)

Pom.xml (part)

```
<profile>
    <id>smoke-tests</id>
    <properties>
        <test.includedGroups>
            ch.ergonomics.junit.category.SmokeTest
        </test.includedGroups>
        <test.excludedGroups></test.excludedGroups>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>fast-tests</id>
    <properties>
        <test.includedGroups>
            ch.ergonomics.junit.category.FastTest
        </test.includedGroups>
        <test.excludedGroups></test.excludedGroups>
    </properties>
</profile>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <groups>${test.includedGroups}</groups>
                <excludedGroups>${test.excludedGroups}</excludedGroups>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

surfire-plugin version: 3.0.0-M5

Comment: It doesn't make sense but, could it be that a new JVM is launched for every single test method? I cannot quite believe that there would be that much overhead in the Surefire plugin.

Comment: I am not sure about this. But the configuration of the surfire plugin is - in respect to fork/thread things - exactly the same in both test runs. I only could imagine that it starts only one JVM when running a test suite, in contrast to starting a JVM for each test class in the category mode.

Comment: One more question, which version of the surefire plugin are you using?

Comment: It's 3.0.0-M5. Editied the question